# SQL WHERE condition depending on form input field

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a form where the user selects a category from the drop-down menu, Now I have another drop-down field which provides the subcategory of the item.

Now I want the second field display only those options depends on the input of category field.

For example

```
<label>Category*</label>
<?php
$sql = "select * from category";
$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo '<select class="custom-select form-control" name="cat" id="cat" 
onChange="getinf(this.value)" required>';
echo '<option value="">'.'</option>';
foreach($stmt as $row){
echo '<option value ="'.$row['cat'].'">'.$row['cat'].'</option>';
}
$test=$row['cat'];
echo '</select>';
?>
```

If the resule is Laptop then I want sql be like this

```
$sql = "select * from store where cat = laptop;
```

So other drop-down will show only laptps name

All this i want at the time of form filling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this with an AJAX request. Get the current option value that has been selected and make an AJAX request to fill the subcategory for the item. This is possible by passing the current selected value of the `<select id="cat">`. Inside of the `populate_subcategory.php` you would run a SQL query that returns all of the possible subcategory's except with the posted value from the AJAX.

Main php:

```
<label>Category*</label>
<?php
$sql = "select * from category";
$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo '<select class="custom-select form-control" name="cat" id="cat" 
onChange="getinf(this.value)" required>';
echo '<option value="">'.'</option>';
foreach($stmt as $row){
echo '<option value ="'.$row['cat'].'">'.$row['cat'].'</option>';
}
$test=$row['cat'];
echo '</select>';

<select name="subcat" id="subcat">
</select>

?>
```

AJAX Script

```
$('#cat').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "populate_subcategory.php",
        data: { "value": $("#cat").val() },
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           $('#subcat').empty();
           $.each(response,function(value) {
           $("#subcat").append('<option value=' + value + '>' + value +'</option>');
        });
       }
    });
});
```

populate_subcategory.php:

```
// Your Passed Value from AJAX
$value = $_POST['value'];

$data = array();

$sql = "select * from store where cat = '$value'";

$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$result = $stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt as $row){
  array_push($data, $row['subcat'];);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

JQuery/AJAX Library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Its display 0 and 1 instant of subcat

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean?

Comment: After selecting category it will display 0 and 1 in subcategory selection option

Comment: So do you need help making the code have the ability to do that, or can you that yourself?

Comment: Thanks now it's working but I have one more issue. Can you please tell me how to refresh select option automatically. For example, right now if I select firstly laptop then it displays all laptop but if I select Mouse after laptop than it will display all laptop and mouse list, So I need to auto refresh select option

Comment: Great, glad it's working. I changed the script (AJAX) above. You need to add `$('#subcat').empty();` inside of success function. That way on the change the select element is emptied and the new values are appended.

Comment: I need one more help, can you please tell me how to send data on more than one field using onChange.

Comment: Modify the data: { .. } of Ajax.